# Refresh relationships in Entiy Framwork

Tags: entity-framework

When clicking the Update Model From Database option in an EF data model, any relationships between tables are not refreshed.  The only way I can find to achieve this is to delete and readd the edmx file, is there another way?

Comment: As stated, this is false. Relationships *are* refreshed. I suspect, however, that there's more to the question than you're letting on. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are seeing a bug in the designer that I see quite a bit.  Refresh the model, close and re-open the designer and you'll actually see the relationship lines between the entities.